# How does OSX know when to delete a file from /tmp directory?

Tags: php, macos, temp

I'm using my system's tmp directory to store files that are only needed temporarily. Files are placed here using PHP's `tmpfilenam()` (not sure if this is relevant).

How does my system determine when a file in this directory should be deleted?  When the file is created, it's given a random string for its name. Is this string significant in determining when the file should be deleted?

Comment: If you downvote a question, leave a comment explaining why. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a script that runs every day to clean up old files in `/tmp`. `/etc/periodic/daily/110.clean-tmps` deletes any files in `/tmp` that haven't been accessed in 3 days. The script can be controlled using settings in `/etc/defaults/periodic.conf`:

```
# 110.clean-tmps
daily_clean_tmps_enable="YES"                           # Delete stuff daily
daily_clean_tmps_dirs="/tmp"                            # Delete under here
daily_clean_tmps_days="3"                               # If not accessed for
daily_clean_tmps_ignore=".X*-lock .X11-unix .ICE-unix .font-unix .XIM-unix"
daily_clean_tmps_ignore="$daily_clean_tmps_ignore quota.user quota.group"
                                                        # Don't delete these
daily_clean_tmps_verbose="YES"                          # Mention files deleted
```